# Digitalocean Dokku Deployment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, digital-ocean, dokku

I am trying to push my yo angular-fullstack MEAN app to Digitalocean with Dokku. I've followed the documentation on Digitalocean's site, but I get the following error when pushing:

```
git push dokku master
Counting objects: 965, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (945/945), done.
Writing objects: 100% (965/965), 242.54 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 965 (delta 668), reused 0 (delta 0)
To dokku@xxxxxxxx.com:xxxxxxxx.com
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@xxxxxxxx.com:xxxxxxxx.com'
```

I set up my droplet using the one click Dokku image, and it's running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this, but I'm not entirely sure how. I checked git status, and it showed that there was an untracked folder. When I resolved that issue, it pushed successfully, though now there is a different issue: how do I serve the dist folder that grunt build creates?

Comment: More information is needed to help with this. Repo link?

Do you have node.js as your server? Using express?

You can use a `.Procfile` file to run the server on deploy to your dokku app or a `.profile.d` folder with config files.